# xindy.pl: Cannot locate bin directory at

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, xindy

I'm using xindy for my acronyms (glossaries).
However the command `makeglossaries latex_file` did not work.
The following error was thrown:

```
xindy.pl: Cannot locate bin directory at C:\Users\GillesCallebautPC\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl line 415.
```

Setup:
- Windows 10 (64-bit)
- MikTex distribution
- Xindy installed through MikTex Package Manager (admin)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add some more information about your setup?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

Remove all installed xindy related packages from the MikTex Package Manager (user). And install all xindy related package from the MikTex Package Manager (admin).

**Old answer**:

I've solved this issue by replacing some code in the `xindy.pl` file.
I've replaced "`$cmd_dir/../../miktex/bin/x64/internal`" with "`C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/internal`" (located around line 406).

Hope this helps for people who will come across the same issue in the future.

Comment: There is no need to manually change xindy.pl (and it is not a good idea too). Deinstall your local versions of the xindy package with the package manager and reinstall it with the package manager (admin).

Comment: I know it is not a good idea to rely on a fixed location. But I've already tried reinstalling the package, without success.

Comment: Well the same discussion just happend three days ago on the miktex list. xindy really should be installed *only* in the main (admin) tree. Check in the package manager (user) for all packages related to xindy and deinstall them. Then reinstall them with the package manager (admin).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was unaware of the difference between the user and admin package managers. Thought that the latter just had some admin rights, that's all. I will try your solution when the server is back. Currently I'm getting the following error: "Error response from server: 500", when installing via the admin package manager.

Comment: The whole miktex site seems to be down. `https://miktex.org/` doesn't answer either.

Comment: Your solution worked! Thank you. I'll edit my answer.