# Error : Call to xindy failed (Tex Live)

Tags: glossaries, xindy

When I run `makeglossaries glossaire`, I get the following error:

```
    Name "Getopt::Std::STANDARD_HELP_VERSION" used only once: possible typo at c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries line 150.
makeglossaries version 4.49 (2021-11-01)
added glossary type 'main' (glg,gls,glo)
xindy  -L french -C utf8 -I xindy -M "glossaire" -t "glossaire.glg" -o "glossaire.gls" "glossaire.glo"
stat(//../../xindy/modules): No such file or directory at c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl line 408
xindy.pl: Cannot locate xindy modules directory at c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl line 409.
C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 2:
perl.exe c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\xindy\xindy.pl -L french -C utf8 -I xindy -M "glossaire" -t "glossaire.glg" -o "glossaire.gls" "glossaire.glo"

***Call to xindy failed***

Check 'glossaire.glg' for details
C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:915: command failed with exit code 2:
perl c:\texlive\2022\texmf-dist\scripts\glossaries\makeglossaries glossaire
```

I use Windows 10 and I don't have the administrator rights. I installed Tex Live as a non admin user.
I already tried to change the path as explained in the question [xindy.pl: Cannot locate bin directory at](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/357285), as follows (around line 411):

```
if ( $is_w32 ) {
   if ( -d "C:/texlive/2022/bin/win32" ) {  # TeX Live
   $cmd_dir = "C:/texlive/2022/bin/win32";
```

I have the same error.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal complete example.